# Changing radio button image in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I need to change images of my radio buttons. I'm trying to do that in this way: when I'm clicking on the image the radio button is activated. That is ok but when I'm all my mapped images are selected then as well, not the one I'm selecting.

Here's my code:

```
  handleRadio(e) {
    const { radioBtnSrc } = this.state;
    radioBtnSrc === './img/bullet_off.png' ?
    this.setState({ radioBtnSrc: './img/bullet_on.png' }) : this.setState({ radioBtnSrc: './img/bullet_off.png' });
  }

  renderSurvey() {
    const { radioBtnSrc } = this.state;
    const surveyItem = mockedData.map((item, i) => 

      <h3 key={item.id} className="questions">
        {item.text}
        {item.answers.map((el, j) => 
          <div key={j}>
            <input onClick={(e) =>  this.handleRadio(e)} type="radio" id={i.toString() + j.toString()} name={i} value={j} />

            <label htmlFor={i.toString() + j.toString()}  className="answers">
              <img src={radioBtnSrc} />
            </label>
          </div> )}
      </h3>
      )

    return surveyItem;
  }
```

Obviously I returning this in render method.

And my mocked data is:

```
const mockedData = 
[
 {
   "id":782299,
   "id_page":258355,
   "number":1,
   "type":0,
   "date_created":"2011-07-14 22:24:46",
   "date_modified":"2011-12-29 18:04:24",
   "text":"Jednokrotne",
   "desc":"",
   "required":1,
   "answers_count":3,
   "options":{
     "shuffle_answers":false,
     "horizontal_display":false
   },
   "answers":[
     {
       "text":"tak",
       "custom_response_available":false
     },
     {
       "text":"nie",
       "custom_response_available":false
     },
     {
       "text":"inne",
       "custom_response_available":true
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   "id":782300,
   "id_page":258355,
   "number":2,
   "type":6,
   "date_created":"2011-07-14 22:24:58",
   "date_modified":"2011-12-29 18:04:13",
   "text":"Wielokrotne",
   "desc":"",
   "required":1,
   "answers_count":4,
   "options":{
     "min":2,
     "max":2,
     "shuffle_answers":false,
     "horizontal_display":false
   },
   "answers":[
     {
       "text":"tak",
       "custom_response_available":false
     },
     {
       "text":"nie",
       "custom_response_available":false
     },
     {
       "text":"mo\u017ce",
       "custom_response_available":false
     },
     {
       "text":"inne",
       "custom_response_available":true
     }
   ]
 }
];
```

Thank you if you could help in that. I'd like to have exactly one image item chosen in order to style radio button bullet.

Comment: The easiest would be if you create a component out of each radio button and set state to every radioComponent. This state will then be sent the parent through a callback function. The problem you have now is that every radio button shares state.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the same key in state for all of the items in your array (`radioBtnSrc`), so updating any of those items is going to update it for all items in the list.

Could you add the `id` as part of the key in state so each item gets its own unique state?

You would need to pass an `id` to `handleRadio`, but then you could do something like this:

```
  handleRadio(e, id) {
    const stateKey = `radioBtnSrc-${id}`;
    this.state[stateKey] === './img/bullet_off.png' ?
    this.setState({ [stateKey]: './img/bullet_on.png' }) : this.setState({ [stateKey]: './img/bullet_off.png' });
  }
```

Another option would be to build up an object and assign it to `radioBtnSrc` and track a property for each key. It might also clean things up to store just the state rather than the full path of the image. e.g. your state could look something like:

```
  const state = {
    buttons: {
      782299: true,
      782300: false
    }
  }
```

Just having those booleans would give you enough information to build the correct UI.